# How to add buttons and labels on frame if its resizable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

i have a code:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x580")
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)

        self.image = Image.open("eth_background.png")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

        self.widget = Button(self, text='Hello world', command=self.quit)
        self.widget.pack(side=LEFT)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)



e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
root.mainloop()
```

I did that bacground is automaticly resize, but now i cant add buttons or lables on a frame. I found it:

```
from Tkinter import *                   

class Hello(Frame):                     
    def __init__(self, parent=None):    
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.make_widgets()

    def make_widgets(self):             
        widget = Button(self, text='Hello world', command=self.quit)
        widget.pack(side=LEFT)

if __name__ == '__main__':  Hello().mainloop()
```

but it obviously doesnt work, how i can do that frame, resizable bacground, and buttons on it?

Comment: Could you be a little more detailed as to what doesn't work? I tried the second example, and it seems to fit your description: the button shows on the frame, the frame resizes.

Comment: yeah, second example its okay, but is without background. I want to create that have a background(.png file) frame should resizes, and on frame should be visible some buttons/labels.

Comment: Why do you think you can't add buttons? What happens when you try?

Comment: there are 'behind' frame, or next to it. when i try add like in my example they are invisible

Comment: Try using `self.background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1, anchor=NW)` instead of `self.background.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)`.